# Profiling memory, disk, cpu, and time from python

Tags: python, profiling

I have a workflow, implemented in python, and I would like to profile memory, disk (IO), cpu, and time information in python in an unobtrusive manner.  This is NOT a question of profiling code, but instead of gathering high-level metrics of how resource-intensive steps in the workflow are.  Any suggestions on how best to go about that?

Comment: Have you considered just having it write to a log as it progresses (with a timestamp) and just using system tools to monitor the process's resource usage?

Comment: Reason I suggest that is because if you don't want to [run the module code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-profile) for some reason, I doubt `python` is going to have a secondary way of doing things.